# pexpect - how to match a lot of blocks in large output strings

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

I am using pexpect to login remote devices to query some metrics.

The output of my command is large (about 15k bytes) and I need to extract many metrics from the output. So I use a big pattern string like

`"key1:([0-9a-zA-Z]*).*key2:([0-9a-zA-Z]*).*key3......"`

to match all the metrics. When the pattern is too long, the expect will block and never terminate.

I've already set the `maxread` to 20k but it doesn't work. Does anyone have some ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Add The code snippet:

```
        session.sendline(command_info["text"])
        ret = session.expect([CMD_PROMPT, pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
        if ret == 1:
            logger.error("EOF error.")
            return
        if ret == 2:
            logger.error("Timeout")
            return

        result = re.match(getExpectedGroupStr(command_info, logger), session.before, re.S)
```

If I use a big pattern string instead of CMD_PROMPT, session.expect will hang and never terminate even if the timeout is reached.

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is the pattern? You don't need one big pattern, you could use several smaller mutually exclusive patterns. I've read upto ~1MB output without issues with `pexpect`. You could try: `output, status = pexpect.runu(command[0], args=command[1:], timeout=None, withexitstatus=1)` , to get everything at once or `pexpect.runu(command[0], args=command[1:], timeout=1, withexitstatus=1, events={pexpect.TIMEOUT: on_timeout, r"key1:\w*": on_key1, r"key2:\w*": on_key2, pexpect.EOF: on_eof})` to process each event individually. If it fails create a minimal but complete code example

Comment: It may not be a pattern issue. When I use a small pattern and I print out the before and after string. The total size is about 5k bytes. The others are truncated. If I only expect the last several bytes of the output (command prompt), I can get all the output (15k bytes). So I work around the issue by getting all the output first, then use regex to match the required metrics.

Comment: I suspect that the larger pattern fails due to limited `searchwindowsize` value. Both suggestions in my previous comment workaround it.

Comment: The code snippet:
            session.sendline(command_info["text"])
            ret = session.expect([CMD_PROMPT, pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
            if ret == 1:
                logger.error("EOF error.")
                return
            if ret == 2:
                logger.error("Timeout")
                return

            result = re.match(getExpectedGroupStr(command_info, logger), session.before, re.S)
If I use a big pattern string instead of CMD_PROMPT, session.expect will hang and never terminate even if the timeout is reached.

Comment: if you need to post a multiline code fragment; don't put it in the comments, update your question instead.

Comment: I didn't change the default searchwindowsize and the doc says that all the buffer will be searched if use the default value. I will try your suggestions. Thanks J.F.